# Image display with 'graph' not working | PySimpleGUI - sg.Graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph, pysimplegui

In my application, there are two windows. The first 'master' window1 is the Image Selector and the second 'slave' window2 is the Image Controller. In the selector window, the user browses and selects the folder containing the images, and then selects one image to display in the Image Controller window. To display the selected image I'm using the sg.Graph() feature of PySimpleGUI.

However, when I run this code, the selected image is NOT being displayed. The white canvas appears in the Controller window but there is no image inside it. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

````
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os.path
import io


# PIL supported image types
img_types = (".png", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".tiff", ".bmp")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# use PIL to read data of one image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def get_img_data(f, maxsize=(1200, 850), first=False):
    """Generate image data using PIL
    """
    img = Image.open(f)
    img.thumbnail(maxsize)
    if first:                     # tkinter is inactive the first time
        bio = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(bio, format="PNG")
        del img
        return bio.getvalue()
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Make Window 1
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def make_win1():
    layout = [
    [
        sg.Text("Image Folder"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-FOLDER-"),
        sg.FolderBrowse(),
    ],
    [
        sg.Listbox(values=[], enable_events=True, size=(40, 20), key="-FILE LIST-")
    ],
    ]
    return sg.Window('Image Selector Window', layout, location=(800,600), finalize=True)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Make Window 2
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def make_win2():
    layout = [    
            [
                sg.Graph(
                canvas_size=(1800, 900),
                graph_bottom_left=(0, 0),
                graph_top_right=(1800, 900),
                key="-GRAPH-",
                change_submits=True,  # mouse click events
                background_color='white',
                drag_submits=True
                )
            ]     
    ]

    return sg.Window('Image Controller Window', layout, size=(1920,1080), finalize=True)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


window1, window2 = make_win1(), None        # start off with 1 window open

while True:  # Event Loop
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        window.close()
        if window == window2:       # if closing win 2, mark as closed
            window2 = None
        elif window == window1:     # if closing win 1, exit program
            break

    elif event == "-FOLDER-":
        folder = values["-FOLDER-"]
        try:
            # Get list of files in folder
            file_list = os.listdir(folder)
        except:
            file_list = []

        fnames = [f for f in file_list if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f)) and f.lower().endswith(img_types)]

        window1["-FILE LIST-"].update(fnames)

    elif event == "-FILE LIST-":  # A file was chosen from the listbox
        if not window2:
            window2 = make_win2()
            graph = window2.Element("-GRAPH-")
        try:
            filename = os.path.join(values["-FOLDER-"], values["-FILE LIST-"][0])

            graph.DrawImage(data=filename, location=(0,540), size = (400,400))
            
        except:
            pass

window1.close()```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong statement,

```py
graph.draw_image(data=filename, location=(0,540), size = (400,400))
```

method defined as

```py
def draw_image(self, filename=None, data=None, location=(None, None)):
"""
:param filename: if image is in a file, path and filename for the image. (GIF and PNG only!)
"""
```

So it should be

```py
graph.draw_image(filename=filename, location=(0,540))
```

It only work for PNG and GIF files, you can use following code for different types of images.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(filanme)
with BytesIO() as output:
    im.save(output, format="PNG")
    data = output.getvalue()
graph.draw_image(data=data, location=(0,540))
```

Comment: Your solution worked! So I'm using your image conversion function with the following line: `graph.draw_image(data=get_img_data(filename), location=(0,540)`. This works. But when I try to change the size and make it small using this extension to the same line: `graph.draw_image(data=get_img_data(filename), location=(0,540), size=(400,400))` no image is displayed. Any idea why?

Comment: There's no option `size` for method `draw_image`, so in `try except` block, it will get error and pass in your code.

Comment: Yeah. Just found that. Thanks Jason. But then any idea how I can make sure that any image the user picks get sized to 400x400? Because the next part of the project is to let the user drag that image around the canvas using the mouse pointer and so I have to make sure that big images don't get dropped in their original size because then there won't be any place to move them around.

Comment: Using `im.thumbnail(size, resample=Image.BICUBIC)`. Before you do it, remember your im will be changed.

Comment: Okay. I will try this. Thanks Jason!